# Format array and include in e-mail using powershell

Tags: arrays, email, powershell, format

I am trying to build a powershell script which collects system up-time information from multiple system and then e-mails it. I want to format the e-mail so I can structure it in a sensible way and later add more information about the systems.

Today I have this script below which collect the uptime information about a list of systems and then passes these information in a array to the SendMail function which includes the array in an e-mail. However the current output is like this.

```
Uptime list:      Restarted 02/19/2013 04:04:52 MyServer01     Computer Uptime:   23 days and 9 hours    Restarted 02/15/2013 04:17:40 MyServer02   Computer Uptime:   27 days and 9 hours
```

I would like to have the output or rather the e-mail text more like:

```
System       | Restarted date/time | Uptime
MyServer01     02/17/2013 04:04:52  25 days and 9 hours
MyServer02     02/17/2013 04:04:52  25 days and 9 hours
```

How can I format the text in the e-mail or do I have to do that before I pass the array to the e-mail function.

The script itself:

`

```
function SendMail([string]$arg1){

     #SMTP server name
     $smtpServer = "mysmtp"

     #Creating a Mail object
     $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage

     #Creating SMTP server object
     $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)

     #Email structure 
     $msg.From = "my@overtherainbow.ddd"
     $msg.ReplyTo = "noreply@overtherainbow.ddd"
     $msg.To.Add("my@overtherainbow.ddd")
     $msg.subject = "System uptime"
     $msg.body = ("List og servers and uptime:" + $arg1 )

     #Sending email 
     $smtp.Send($msg)}


function CheckUptime($listofservers){
    $k =@()
    foreach($s in $listofservers){
        $Booted = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $s
        $Calc = [DateTime]::Now - $Booted.ConvertToDateTime($Booted.LastBootUpTime)
        $k +=       "   Restarted " + 
        $Booted.ConvertToDateTime($Booted.LastBootUpTime) +
        " " + $s + " " +
        "    Computer Uptime:   " + 
        $Calc.days + " " +
        "days and", $Calc.hours + " hours"
        }
        return $k
}



#Defining list og servers
$listofservers = "MyServer01", "MyServer02"

#Calling function
$message = CheckUptime($serverlist)
SendMail($message)
```

`

Answer (score 2):

First, it shows little effort when your sample is not even a working sample. Variable typos etc.

As a solution, why don't you create custom objects containing the data for each server and output it as an array?. Something like:

```
PS > function CheckUptime($listofservers){
    $res = @()

    foreach($s in $listofservers){
        $boot = Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $s | % { $_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastBootUpTime) }
        $uptime = [DateTime]::Now - $boot
        $res += New-Object psobject -Property @{
            Server = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($s)
            BootTime = $boot
            Uptime = "{0} days and {1} hours" -f $uptime.Days, $uptime.Hours
        }
    }

    #Output
    $res
}

$myservers = "localhost", "localhost"

$str = "List of servers and uptime:`r`n"

$str += CheckUptime $myservers | Out-String

PS > $str
List of servers and uptime:

Server                            Uptime                           BootTime
------                            ------                           --------
Localhost                         8 days and 6 hours               06.03.2013 09:33:37
Localhost                         8 days and 6 hours               06.03.2013 09:33:37
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Format-Table` to format the data as desired, and pipe that into `Out-String` to convert into a single string containing the formatted data.

Then append that to your email content.

This relies on the data gathering replacing building a single string with building a custom object with separate fields for each different column.

Eg (incomplete, but should give you the idea)

```
$serverData = $serverList | Foreach-Object { GetServerData $_ } | 
   Format-Table Name, 
                @(l='Boot Time'; e={$_.BootTime.ToLocalTime()}},
                @(l='Uptime'; e={FormatUptime([DateTime]::UtcNow - $_.BootTime}} |
   Out-String

$emailBody += $serverData
```

where the referenced functions are already defined, along the lines of:

```
function GetServerData {
  params([string]$name)

  $os = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $name
  $bootTimeLocal = $os.ConvertToDateTime($os.LastBootUpTime)

  new-object PSObject -property @{
    Name = $name;
    # Keep everything in UTC to avoid confusion in calcs,
    # TODO FIX: Use the remote machine's timezone for this....
    BootTime = $bootTimeLocal.ToUniversalTime()
  }
}
```

and

```
function FormatUptime {
  params([TimeSpan]$time)

  ...
}
```

Summary:

- Use `Format-*` cmdlets to format, and if not immediately passing to output (and the default `Out-Default` appended to the end of every pipeline without an `Out-*`) then convert to a string with `Out-String`.
- Keep data types in their native type as long as possible. Do not convert to human readable forms until you have to. Thus information is not lost.
- Make use of custom objects and properties (especially NoteProperties) to create your own object "types" to keep related information together.